# Git: Fork as an alternative to Sourcetree. Different behaviour when I push local feature branch to the origin. Why?

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree, git-fork

Yesterday I was setting up new account on macOS and the process of registering Sourcetree annoyed me so much (they force you to create Bitbucket account that I don't need) that I decided to look for another GUI alternative.

After initial try I reached to the following issue when pushing a local feature branch.

1. I have a repository on Github (origin) with `master` and `develop` branches.
2. On my local Mac I created a feature branch from `develop` via iTerm by typing `git checkout -b feature/more-sync-logic-4 origin/develop`.
3. I made some commits and when I hit `"push"` I was expecting the `feature/more-sync-logic-4` branch **to be pushed to Github so that I can create pull request, review and merge to develop**.

Instead of above, all my committed changes **were immediately (straight away) pushed and merged to develop on Github**! The feature branch was not pushed on remote origin. Why?

Normally when I do exactly the same steps in SourceTree and I click "push" I see below window:

[image]

where checkbox is next to the branch I want to push.

This apparently does not appear on Git-Fork as since I press `"push"`, the only thing I see is

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: “The feature branch was not pushed on remote origin. Why?” Because you said to create the feature branch off the remote tracking branch `origin/develop`? Isn’t this exactly what that means? I don’t understand why you didn’t just say `git checkout -b myFeature` plain and simple and then push the branch up to origin. That is the usual feature branch pattern as described on GitHub. Of course maybe _I’m_ missing something.